# is(unit_step(x)*unit_step(x) = unit_step(x)) evaluates to false

Tags: maxima

We are giving students some exercises, where their solutions are evaluated with maxima.

The answer involves the unit step function. The evaluation in maxima seems to go okay, except that there seems to be missing some algebraic rules on the `unit_step` functions.

For example `is(unit_step(x)*unit_step(x) = unit_step(x))` evaluates to false. It is quite unlikely that the student gives the answer in such a form, but still we don't want to have the possibility that the student gives a good answer, that is evaluated as incorrect.

Below is a screenshot of an answer we try to evaluate with maxima involving the `unit_step` function (that we defined as `u`):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maxima doesn't know much about unit_step at present (circa Maxima 5.41). This is just a shortcoming, there's no reason for it, except that nobody has gotten around to doing the work. That said, it's not too hard to make some progress.

The simplifier for multiplication merges identical terms into powers:

```
(%i3) unit_step(x)*unit_step(x);
                                   2
(%o3)                     unit_step (x)
```

So let's define a simplifier rule which reduces positive powers of unit_step. (I was going to say positive integer powers, but a moment's thought shows that the same identity holds for noninteger positive powers as well.)

```
(%i4) matchdeclare (aa, lambda ([e], e > 0)) $
(%i5) matchdeclare (xx, all) $
(%i6) tellsimpafter (unit_step(xx)^aa, unit_step(xx));
(%o6)                  [^rule1, simpexpt]
```

Let's try it.

```
(%i7) unit_step(x)*unit_step(x);
(%o7)                     unit_step(x)
(%i8) is (unit_step(x)*unit_step(x) = unit_step(x));
(%o8)                         true
(%i9) unit_step(t - 5)^(1/4);
(%o9)                   unit_step(t - 5)
(%i10) assume (m > 0);
(%o10)                       [m > 0]
(%i11) unit_step(2*u + 1)^m;
(%o11)                 unit_step(2 u + 1)
```

So far, so good. Of course this is just one identity and there are others that could be useful. Since this rule is not built-in, one would have to load that definition in order to make use of it; that would be bothersome if you intend for others to use this.

For the record, the only simplification for unit_step which I found in the Maxima source code is in share/contrib/integration/abs_integrate.mac, which contains a function unit_step_mult_simp, which applies the identity `unit_step(a)*unit_step(b) --> unit_step(min(a, b))`.